# how to send some data from worker thread to UI thread?

Tags: android

how many ways to send data from worker thread to main thread ?  or we can say There are how many way to change UI view data from any worker thread other then this?

1. through the AsyncroniousTask .
2. through the hadler.sendMessage()

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: ((MyPostActivity) this.context)
      .loadMyPostListView(this.streamDetails);

Comment: Which is sending data to MainUI thread from Worker thread all you need to do is to send Context or Activity Object from your calling Activity to your AsyncroniousTask and mentioned answer below you can take help from it. Thanks.

Comment: @SALMAN - first thanks for quick responce but your answer is little bit confusing. could you please give some sample code or any related link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: runOnUiThread is also my most favorite way to cooporate thread and activity. But before call runOnUiThread, you should check if activity is finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

You also may pass a reference to your `View` object to the worker Thread and when event comes call `View.post(Runnable)` which is almost analog of `Handler.post(Runnable)` method